# wchar ends with single null byte or two of them?

Tags: c++, string, null, byte, wchar

I just don't understand and can't find much info about wchar end.

If it ends with single null byte, how it know it not string end yet, if something like that "009A" represent one of unicode symbols?

If it ends with two null bytes? Well, I am not sure about it, need confirmation.

Comment: in C++, i didn't knew wchar exist somewhere else

Comment: Somewhat related: [Making a WCHAR null terminated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1806297/making-a-wchar-null-terminated). Might be some hints in there as to how to approach this.

Comment: In C++, `wchar_t` (not `wchar`) is a predefined type.  In C, `wchar_t` is a typedef defined in `<stddef.h>`.  In both cases, the size is implementation-defined; on my system its size is 4 bytes (32 bits).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since a wide string is an array of wide characters, it couldn't even end in an one-byte NUL. It is a two-byte NUL. (Arrays in C/C++ can only hold members of the same type, so of the same size).

Also, for ASCII standard characters, there always is one or three one-byte 0, as only extended characters start by a non-zero first byte (depending on whether `wchar_t` is 16 or 32 bit wide - for simplicity, I assume 16-bit and little-endian):

```
HELLO is 72 00 69 00 76 00 76 00 79 00 00 00
```

Comment: err, so if i access array of wchar like that: arr[0] = 0; it will set to zero first and second byte automatically?

Comment: @Kosmos (If this is not yet clear, I suggest you to read a good tutorial on C pointers and arrays!)

Comment: Is there anyway that wchar can be converted to char? I reversing chinese app, but as i see they are using char* for text manipulations. Could it be just wchar array converted to char* of double size?

Comment: @Kosmos There are libraries with which you can convert UTF-16 (wide strings) to UTF-8.

Comment: @H2CO3: On my system, `sizeof (wchar_t) == 4`. You also seem to be making assumptions about endianness.

Comment: @KeithThompson yup, that sizeof is perfectly fine. And no, I am not making assumptions about endianness - whether it be little or big endian, it's easier to conceive the essentials if I write all this using big endian notation...

Comment: I am trying to solve task to scan Chinese exe for text strings, for that i need to know how many bytes in the end - two null bytes or 4

Comment: @H2CO3: "only extended characters *start* by a non-zero *first* byte" -- that assumes big-endian (with your recent edit, you've made the assumption explicit).

Comment: @KeithThompson yes, sorry, you're correct - modern processor architectures that count use the counterintuitive little-endian notation, so that's why I was confusing them...

Comment: Since this question is about the double byte null at the end of hte string, it's very strange that your sample string doesn't demonstrate that.

Comment: HELLO is 72 00 69 00 76 00 76 00 79 00 in little-endian byte order. The "end" in "endian" actually means the "front end" of the sequence: "In big-endian format, the most significant byte is stored first (has the lowest address) or sent first, then the following bytes are stored or sent in decreasing significance order, with the least significant byte stored last (having the highest address) or sent last." https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 5):

Here you can read a bit more of Wide Characters: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character#Size_of_a_wide_character

Terminations are L'\0', means a 16-bit null so it's like two 8-bit null chars.

Remember that "009A" is only 1 wchar so is not a null wchar.

Answer (score 5):

In C (quoting [the N1570 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), section 7.1.1):

> A *wide string* is a contiguous sequence of wide characters terminated
>   by and including the first null wide character.

where a "wide character" is a value of type `wchar_t`, which is defined in `<stddef.h>` as an integer type.

I can't find a definition of "wide string" in [the N3337 draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3337.pdf) of the C++ standard, but it should be similar. One minor difference is that `wchar_t` is a typedef in C, and a built-in type (whose name is a keyword) in C++. But since C++ shares most of the C library, including functions that act on wide strings, it's safe to assume that the C and C++ definitions are compatible. (If someone can find something more concrete in the C++ standard, please comment or edit this paragraph.)

In both C and C++, the size of a `wchar_t` is implementation-defined.  It's typically either 2 or 4 bytes (16 or 32 bits, unless you're on a very exotic system with bytes bigger than 8 bits). A wide string is a sequence of wide characters (`wchar_t` values), terminated by a null wide character.  The terminating wide character will have the same size as any other wide character, typically either 2 or 4 bytes.

In particular, given that `wchar_t` is bigger than `char`, a *single* null byte does not terminate a wide string.

It's also worth noting that byte order is implementation-defined. A wide character with the value `0x1234`, when viewed as a sequence of 8-bit bytes, might appear as any of:

- `0x12`, `0x34`
- `0x34`, `0x12`
- `0x00`, `0x00`, `0x12`, `0x34`
- `0x34`, `0x12`, `0x00`, `0x00`

And those aren't the only possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

if you declare

```
WCHAR tempWchar[BUFFER_SIZE];
```

you make it null

```
for (int i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i++)
            tempWchar[i] = NULL;
```